# JSON key as a JSON value in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, express

Someone knows how I can to convert this JSON:

```
{"MASCULINO": 10, "FEMENINO": 20, "NO GENERO": 70}
```

To this JSON:

```
"MASCULINO": {
    "MASCULINO": 10
},
"FEMENINO": {
    "FEMENINO": 20
},
"NO GÉNERO": {
    "NO GÉNERO": 70
}
```

I do this because I have this error [XLSX-CHART cannot graphic simple JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51228075/xlsx-chart-cannot-graphic-simple-json) and this is the only solution that I found...

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` for this:

```js
const obj = {"MASCULINO": 10, "FEMENINO": 20, "NO GENERO": 70};

const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => ({
  ...acc,
  [curr]: {
    [curr]: obj[curr],
  }
}), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

use `lodash` lib

```
const obj = {"MASCULINO": 10, "FEMENINO": 20, "NO GENERO": 70};
const newObj = _.transform(obj, function(result, value, key) {
     return result[key] = { [key]: value };
}, {});
console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: The code of Alan Friedman is more simple, but thank you same :)